# Given APP secret and client ID retrieve Facebook user access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

The following Facebook URL:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Shows all the user tokens from the Facebook user created apps.

Here is how I can retrieve at the moment my Facebook *User Access Token* manually ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401241/how-to-get-a-facebook-access-token-using-appid-and-app-secret-without-any-login)):

### OAuth 2.0

1. With the standard OAuth 2.0 implementation, the first step is to invoke the *OAuth Dialog* of the service provider (facebook)-

   > `\GET  http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth`
   >
   > Parameters-
   >
   > - `client_id` (APP ID)
   > - `redirect_uri` (App's Redirect Url)
   > - `scope` (permissions - *optional*)
   >
   > Returns-
   >
   > - `code` (appended with the redirect url)
2. After the user successfully authenticated the app, a `code` is returned by the service provider(facebook) appended with the `redirect_url` passed. So you'll be redirected to-

   > `{redirect-url}?code=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

   We use this `code` then and request for the **`access_token`**-

   > `\GET  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token`
   >
   > Parameters-
   >
   > - `client_id` (APP ID)
   > - `client_secret` (APP Secret)
   > - `code`
   > - `redirect_uri`

This works fine, but as you can see it requires a manual step in order to retrieve the *code* from the redirected URL and add it to the second URL that returns the *User Access Token*. However I don't know how to make this process automatic, that is, given an user *App ID* and *App Secret*, retrieve my *User Access Token* without manual steps.

Is there any way to retrieve the user access token with a PHP script?

Here is what I've tried in order to achieve this using the PHP SDK:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '<my app id>',
  'app_secret' => '<my app secret>',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

However *$accessToken* returns NULL.

May be there is some other way to do this using the Facebook PHP SDK?

Comment: That is not possible – that “manual step” is part of the OAuth flow, and necessary. You need user interaction within a browser (or a webview component of some sorts) to get a user access token. (If the user authorized your app before already, they won’t have to do it again – the login dialog will just shortly pop up in that situation, and close resp. redirect back to the app immediately.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automate getting a user token or to automate user authorization. That would make the whole user authorization pointless, and there is no serious use case for it. The only way to get a User Token is to manually authorize a user (by building a manual login flow or using one of the SDKs).

Comment: The use case would be to retrieve the access token each time the functional tests are executed (in my case using behat). If you always use the same token for the tests, sooner or later the tests will break. Getting my user access token automatically would fix this problem.

Comment: your only chance is to authorize manually and store an extended user token, it is valid for 60 days